# In TextField when type @@ open the date-picker angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have a one text box when type the **@** get the `usersList` when type the **#** get the `tagsList` and when type the **@@** open the date picker I'm using **ngx-bootstrap datepicker.**

-I'm tried to add dynamically `bsDatepicker` it added successfully but datepicker dialog not get. I think it not registered in DOM perfectly.

HTML

```
        <div *ngIf="addCard" class="mx-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" (keyup)="getVal()" id="input_2" [formControl]="cardName" >
           <ng-container *ngIf="drpBind">
            <div class="searchresults" *ngFor="let i of lstbindData; let index = index" (click)="selectVal(i)">{{i}}
            </div>
           </ng-container>
       </div>
```

TS

```
  lstbindData: any = [];
  addCard: boolean = false;
  drpBind: boolean = false;
  getDatePicker: boolean = false;
  cardName = new FormControl();

 getVal() {
  const val = this.cardName.value;
  console.log('val', val);
  const value = val == '@' ? 1 : val == '#' ? 2 : val == '@@' ? 3 : 4;
   if (value == 1) {
     this.drpBind = true;
     this.lstbindData = this._cS.getAtkeywords();
   }
   else if (value == 2) {
     this.drpBind = true;
     this.lstbindData = this._cS.getHaskeywords();
   }
   else if (value == 3) {
     this.drpBind = false;
     var getEle1 = document.getElementById('input_2'); 
     getEle1.setAttribute('bsDatepicker', ''); //I'm trying to setAttribute it added successfully but datepicker it not getting.
   }
    else {
      this.drpBind = false;
    }
 }
```

Anyone have Idea please share it.

Thanks.